# Formally, can a polynomial include terms like $x^{-1}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Polynomial: an expression of more than two algebraic terms, especially the sum of several terms that contain different powers of the same variable(s).
>
> Example: $3x^{2}-4x+5$

We can rewrite this is $3x^{2}+\left(-4x^{1}\right)+5x^{0}$, with the degrees in decreasing order. However, would an expression like $3x^{2}+\left(-4x^{1}\right)+5x^{0}+2x^{-1}$ count as a polynomial?

Comment: No, not a polynomial

Comment: Well that answers my question! Would it be possible for you to instead write that as  an answer? Questions that are answered in the comments usually get closed. Thanks±

Comment: There is a thing called a [Laurent Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurent_polynomial) that includes things like this.

Comment: The [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20a%20polynomial%20is,x2%20%E2%88%92%204x%20%2B%207.) is very clear about this:"and positive-integer powers of variables." If you think a question will be closed, then first look up the (correct) definition before posting.

Comment: If your polynomial is in an equation, and it is set equal to a constant or power of x, then you can multiply through by x to get rid of the negative exponent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, the powers appearing in a polynomial must be non-negative integers, see the first paragraph of [Polynomial - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial).

Answer (score -3):

Polynomials can only have exponents greater than or equal to 0, so $x^{-1}$ can never be in a polynomial.